# javascript not working

Tags: javascript

```
window.location='operations.php?atnd_id='+id+'&at_dis='+d;
```

is not redirecting to operations.php

Comment: Got nothing to do with PHP, tag removed.

Answer (score 2):

change it to

```
window.location.href='operations.php?atnd_id='+id+'&at_dis='+d;
```

Comment: @aparna accept this ans now! :D

Comment: oh come on. there's more to SO than answering broadside of a barn questions for points.

Comment: @greg: think of SO as a store.. store of knowledge. People come asking for help and pay with points. It's really not much to ask: just click one single button to show your gratitude.

Comment: or, think of SO as a place to answer programming questions because they interest you and you enjoy helping people.

Comment: @greg: Now, I think you are thinking SO as a place of social networking, you should be agree with Shadow